# Partition beginning or end?

Tags: installation, partitioning

What is the difference of the location of the disk at the beginning or end, I would like an explanation please.?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 5):

Your question is a possibly similar to [boot - Is having the 'swap' partition at the 'beginning' better than at the 'end'? - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56883/is-having-the-swap-partition-at-the-beginning-better-than-at-the-end)

The discussion simply states that putting the partition at the 'beginning' side of the hard drive makes it a little faster than putting the partition at the end because the closer the blocks to the center of the disk, the faster and lesser the read/write cycles would be.

Comment: Careful, this *assumes* a mechanical hard disk. This is not necessarily the case with "disks" these days. Still +1 for the answer.

Comment: I do not mean only the swap but / usr / var / tmp /, they should be on the BEGINNING or END?